# Software to stream Video from Server

Tags: video-streaming

Are there any out of the box programs / server software that I can install on my server to stream videos? I found [XMoov](http://stream.xmoov.com/) while searching, are there any others? Which one is best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting and did not get any good answer, i will give a try to : http://stream.xmoov.com/ and let you know if i go the manual way, thanks anyway !

Answer (score -1):

u Can youse javascript to ajax fetch the video, display in browser. But i don'\t know if that will scale to millions of use.rs